# How to add two lines of number from a file in bash shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell

I was trying to add the numbers from a file in shell and I am kinda stuck. I am new to bash and I dont know how to do it. 
My file example is like this.

cat temp

23 49

35 50

what I want to do is to add 23 and 35 and to add 49 and 50. Any ideas will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using `awk`:

```
 awk '{f1+=$1;f2+=$2} END{print f1" "f2}' temp
```

> what if i want to save f1 and f2 to another file call temp1, how can i
>   do that?

Redirect the standard output to file `temp1`.

```
 awk '{f1+=$1;f2+=$2} END{print f1" "f2}' temp > temp1
```

Comment: what if i want to save f1 and f2 to another file call temp1, how can i do that?

Comment: @soe:redirect it to temp1. `... temp >temp1`

Comment: thanks man. i will try that. but i dont want to delete temp. it is not going to delete it, is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bc to eval any numeric expression:

```
echo "32 + 33" | bc
```

Or for the whole file:

```
sed 's/ /+/' < temp|bc
```

Comment: the question wants the sum of columns, not rows. Clever solution though.

Comment: oops ... my bad :) ... awk is definitely the way to go :)